# Macbook crashes during start up

Tags: macbook-pro, crash, login, startup

My 13" macbook pro mid 2012 won't get through halfway the loading bar. After pressing the power button, the apple logo appear , i hear the chime, it would load halfway then just shuts off.

I have tried to login with different keyboard commands, but it doesn't even reach the login window. Please help

Comment: Start with [Apple Hardware Test](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201257) by holding “D” while booting. You can also try `Cmd-V` for Verbose mode. Record the boot messages with your phone so you can see what messages are being generated. Update your question with this info.

Comment: Try also Safe Mode. See https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201262